# Validation não retorna array com erros

Tags: laravel

Estou tentando utilizar o validation do laravel para validar um formulário, porém não estou recebendo o array de erros

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class Curriculos extends Controller {
public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
      'nome' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $curriculos = $request->all();

    $curriculos['dt-nascimento'] = str_replace('/', '-', $curriculos['dt-nascimento']);
    $curriculos['dt-nascimento'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($curriculos['dt-nascimento']));

    $curriculos['dt-inicio'] = $this->formatDate($curriculos['dt-inicio']);

    $curriculos['dt-conclusao'] = $this->formatDate($curriculos['dt-conclusao']);

    $curriculo = new Curriculo;

    if($curriculo->create($curriculos)){
      return redirect('/');
    }


}
```

**View**

```
 <?php var_dump($errors->all()); ?>
 <form class="" action="{{url('/api/send')}}" method="post">
   @csrf
  ......
```

**Resultado do Var_dump()**

```
 array(0) { }
```

Comment: Onde está definir essa rota em web.php ou api.php

Comment: Em api, como Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando são utilizadas rotas definidas em api.php, como referido pelo *Luhan Salimena* não é aplicado o *middleware group* *ShareErrorsFromSession* (ver configuração em Kernel.php).

Sem aplicação desse *middleware group* a variável *$errors* não é passada para a *View*

Veja a documentação em https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

A rotas em api.php são adequadas para pedidos via Ajax nesse caso por defeito quando existe um erro de validação vai obter uma resposta Json com o código 422 com todos os erros encontrados.

Sugiro que altere a sua rota para web.php que parece ser mais adequado ao seu caso.

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado :D